# Convert $_.ErrorDetails.Message to Array in powershell

Tags: powershell

I may be asking the wrong question here but I have:

```
try{
        $data = Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $url -Headers $Header -Body $Body`
    }catch{
        write-host "Failed:" -ForegroundColor red
        write-host $_.ErrorDetails.Message
        
        
    }
```

the output is:

```
{
  "errorCode" : "XXXXX",
  "message" : "Request rate exceeded",
  "errors" : [ {
    "errorCode" : "XXXX",
    "message" : "Request rate exceeded"
  } ]
```

I need:

```
"message" : "Request rate exceeded"
```

as a variable so that I can write some code around it.

There are probably multiple ways to do this but I feel like there should be a simple way to convert this to an array and do something like:

```
$x = $_.ErrorDetails.Message
$x.message
```

I guess in a pinch I can parse it out. Thanks for any help you have to offer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `$_.ErrorDetails.Message` contains *JSON* text.

If so, you can use [`ConvertFrom-Json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json) to parse it:

```
$x = ConvertFrom-Json $_.ErrorDetails.Message
$x.message # -> 'Request rate exceeded'
```